# What is the 4th channel in an image?

Tags: python, image, numpy, rgb, cmyk

what does the column imply when randomly generating an image using `np.random.randint`

```
img = np.random.randint(255, size=(4,4,3), dtype='uint8')
```

This creates a 4 by 4 pixel, with a matrix of 3 columns.

```
img = np.random.randint(255, size=(4,4,4), dtype='uint8')
```

This creates a 4 by 4 pixel, with a matrix of 4 columns.

What is the job of the column in the matrix in this case?

Comment: The three columns are often the red, green and blue channels. With four channels, it is often an alpha channel that specifies the opaque level of that pixel.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Is the fourth column then white?

Comment: well first of all you should note that it depends on how you *represent* the image. There are other color spaces than RGB. With four channels, it can be an alpha-channel.

Comment: @Matthew let me know if my answer helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice question. We usually call channels what you call columns.

---

A **RGB** image has 3 channels: red, green and blue.

A **CMYK** image has four channels: cyan, magenta, yellow, and black.

---

**Visually**:

[image: RGB]

[image: CMYK]

Answer (score 3):

One can not say what the components of a pixel represent. Or at least not with certainty. It depends on the [*color space* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_space) you select.

In order to store a color, you need to represent that color. There are several ways to do that. A common way to do that is with the [*RGB color model* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model). Where one uses three channels: one for **R**ed, one for **G**reen and one for **B**lue. This model is based on the assumption that the human eye has three kinds of light receptors, for each of these colors. It is common in for monitors as well, since a computer monitor has three sorts of [subpixels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel#Subpixels) each to render one of the color channels. Sometimes an extra channel **A**lpha is added, making it an *ARGB* color scheme. The alpha channel then describes the level of transparency of that pixel. This is useful if you for example want to add one image over another one, and some parts of the image.

Another color system is the [*HSL* color system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV), where the color space is seen as a cylindrical shape one, and the three attribute **H**ue, **S**aturation, and **L**ightness describe the angle, radius and height in the cylinder respectively. This is contrast to an *RGB* color system, that can be seen as a cube.

For printing purposes, often the [*CMYK color model*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK) is used: with a channel for **C**yan, **M**agent, **Y**ellow and Blac**k**. These are often the ink cardridges in a basic printer.

In short, you thus can not tell what the color scheme is. According to numpy, this is just a *4×4×3* or *4×4×4* array. It is only by *interpreting* the numbers, for example according to a color scheme, that we can make sense out of it.

OpenCV has a function to convert one color scheme into another. As you can see, it supports a large range of [conversions](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html). It has extensive [documentation on the color schemes](https://docs.opencv.org/master/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html) as well.