# How to Convert RGB imgage to NIR+RGB image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, image-processing

Is it possible to convert RGB image to RGB+NIR image?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/58900493/2681662

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **OpenCV** like this:

```
import cv2

fourChannel = cv2.cvtColor(threeChannel, cv2.COLOR_RGB2RGBA)
```

Or you can use Numpy to make a new, empty channel of same size and type as your original, and stack it onto your 3 channel image:

```
import numpy as np

newEmpty = np.zeros_like(threeChannel[...,0])
fourChannel = np.dstack((threeChannel, newEmpty))
```

Comment: The Second Method you shared worked for me, At least my code is accepting the images i converted from 3 channel to 4 channel.
can you explain what is the 4th channel in your method, Is it all zeros?

Comment: Yes ,the fourth channel is all zeroes. You can add 255 to it if you want to fill it with that value.

Comment: if i want to fill the new channel with any other value in float or double the ho can i do that?

Comment: You can use `fourChannel[..., 3] = 127` to fill the new channel with the value 127.